# How to read value from objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to `node.js`.
I have data from a `JSON` file that looks like this :

```
[
 {
  "name": "A
 },
 {
  "name": "B",
 },
 {
  "name": "C",
 },
]
```

The console output that I wanted looks like this
`"A", "B", "C"`

Can you guys help me? thanks!

Comment: arr.map(item => item.name) would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the map function.

[map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
let value = [
 {
  "name": "A"
 },
 {
  "name": "B",
 },
 {
  "name": "C",
 },
];

let result = value.map(x => x.name);
// this is called "Object Destructuring"
let result2 = value.map({name} => name);
// console logging => ["A","B","C"]
console.log(result, result2);
```